# What is the library to be installed for `jasper.h` header file?

Tags: apt, software-installation, 18.04, compiling, libraries

I am trying to build Opencv on Ubuntu 18.04.

When I run `make` I get the error:

```
grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:59:10: fatal error: jasper/jasper.h: No such file or directory
 #include <jasper/jasper.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

I had already `jasper` installed and installed `libjasperreports-java`. However the file `jasper.h` cannot be found in my system. Is there any library I can install with `apt install` to get that file?

Comment: No official package provides that file on 18.04: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=jasper.h

Answer (score 6):

`jasper.h` is part of the `libjasper-dev` package. This package is not available in Ubuntu 18.04. So try downloading it and install using

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/j/jasper/libjasper-dev_1.900.1-debian1-2.4ubuntu1.3_amd64.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/j/jasper/libjasper1_1.900.1-debian1-2.4ubuntu1.3_amd64.deb

sudo apt-get install ./libjasper-dev_1.900.1-debian1-2.4ubuntu1.3_amd64.deb ./libjasper1_1.900.1-debian1-2.4ubuntu1.3_amd64.deb
```

Comment: I get this error `The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libjasper-dev : Depends: libjasper1 (= 1.900.1-debian1-2.4ubuntu1.2) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
`

Comment: Edited my answer. Please try again