# Where is jasper.h?

Tags: 18.04

After updating an Ubuntu18.04 system, I installed jasper with

```
sudo apt-get install jasper
```

It installed a bunch of things but I cannot find jasper.h. Thanks.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1079956/what-is-the-library-to-be-installed-for-jasper-h-header-file

Comment: It seems to work. Thanks.